# Where to Configure HttpClient for Both Tests and Live

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

This sounds like a very basic and common question, but I can't find a clear answer and I've tried various approaches. I'm using ASP.NET Core. I want to configure HttpClient, among other things, setting SslProtocol to Tls12.

This won't work because `services.AddHttpClient` requires the class to take a HttpClient through injection.

```
public class BluePayHttpClient : HttpClient
{
    public BluePayHttpClient() : base(new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        CheckCertificateRevocationList = true,
        SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
    })
    { }
}
```

If I take HttpClient via injection... then I'm unable to set those settings here! Because HttpClientHandler must be set in the HttpClient's constructor.

Then I can set those settings in Startup, but

1. The connection logic, protocol, base address and stuff like that is part of the specific module and I prefer to keep that together.
2. If I set it up in Startup, then it's not being configured for Integration Tests! I need to duplicate the configuration code, and duplicates are bad.

What's the best way to set this up?

And if I'm not configuring those base options in BluePayHttpClient, then that class really isn't doing much at all... should I instead inject the HttpClient directly into the classes using it? `services.AddHttpClient<IPaymentProcessor, PaymentProcessor>` does feel a bit awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better approach after reading [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (you may want to read this carefully)

Using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package allows building the Dependency Injection container and thus testing the service configuration chain just like if you were running live.

Benefits:

- No need to duplicate HttpClient configuration code.
- It tests the whole DI container configuration.
- It allows testing web pages and controllers; or testing regular classes.

Downsides:

- Generic class library test project must be linked to a front-end Web project to read the configuration, even if it is used by several projects.
- Class library test project cannot be used in the other web projects.

Overall... it seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

> should I instead inject the HttpClient directly into the classes using it?

Yes.

A typed client can be registered and it can also be configured explicitly for that type

```
services
    .AddHttpClient<IPaymentProcessor, PaymentProcessor>(c => {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
        //other client configuration here.
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => {
        //configure handler
        return new HttpClientHandler() {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            CheckCertificateRevocationList = true,
            SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
        };
    });
```

Reference [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

The configuration can also be done in their specific modules and exposed via extension methods that are invoked in Startup.

Comment: That's what I was doing; before realizing that connections weren't working for Integration Tests. Furthermore, this prevents me from specifying a scope for PaymentProcessor. Does it become Singleton? I could go back to duplicating the configuration code but there's got to be a better way? Unless I call Startup code as part of integration tests.